# Duplicate class com.google.common found in modules guava error after migrating to Androidx

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    implementation 'net.gotev:speech:1.3.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.haozhang.libary:android-animated-recording-view:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev204-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.6'
    implementation 'com.unstoppable:submitbutton:1.1.3'
    implementation 'ru.github.igla:ferriswheel:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.0.8'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.mapzen.android:speakerbox:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'

    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-speech', version: '1.22.0'

}
```

I am getting this error when I try to build my project:

```
Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.Beta found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Absent found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$1 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Ascii found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$1 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$2 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$3 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$4 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$5 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$StringConverter found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$1 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$And found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$BitSetMatcher found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$FastMatcher found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$NegatedFastMatcher found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$RangesMatcher found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Charsets found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$1 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$1$1 found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$ConverterComposition found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$FunctionBasedConverter found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$IdentityConverter found in modules guava-28.1-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and guava-jdk5-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After many hours of research I found the solution. The problematic dependency was this:

> 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev204-1.23.0'

I solved it by using:

```
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev204-1.23.0'){
        exclude group:'com.google.guava'
    }
```

If you face a similar issue, try to create a new Android project and import only the dependencies from your previous project. Then divide and conquer until you find the problematic dependency.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, do you need both com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0 and com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android dependencies?

I've often seen those duplicate class errors arise in two scenarios:
1) Two libraries are using different versions of the same dependency.

2) Using androidx and support library together in a project. Your two guava dependencies may be using google commons classes that are present in androidx and support library.

You should verify that all support library dependencies are replaced with androidx and if that is done, consider excluding the conflicting classes packages from either com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0 or com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android.

Comment: I don't think I need guava. The problem is that I can't remove it from my project.

Comment: can anyone give a step by step on how to "excluding the conflicting classes packages from either com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0 or com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android."

Comment: @KofiYah try to add this line in build.gradle:
configurations {
    implementation.exclude module:'guava-jdk5'
}

Answer (score 1):

may be it's too late. However, I am writing an answer to your problem.

I had the same issue. I was using the Youtube Data API v3. After few searches and seeing answers from Stackoverflow, I mixed all of them and somehow it worked!!

Here is all I did and it worked.

Added configurations to app level build.gradle file. Like below

```
configurations {
implementation.exclude module:'gauva-jdk5'
all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture' }
```

Added these two lines in dependency block

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava' implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android'
```

And inside the dependencies needed for youtbe data api I hadded
exclude group:'com.google.guava'

Just like below

```
implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group:'com.google.guava'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group:'com.google.guava'
    }
```

to more check out https://stackguides.com/questions/61480581/duplicate-class-found-in-modules-guava-26-0-android-jar-and-guava-jdk5-17-0-jar#

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error

"Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.Beta found in modules jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)"

I implemented Youtube in my app using YouTube data api v3, while adding this app as a module in my, main app I got same error.

I resolved this error by removing some dependency

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

Above all three library I added but this was useless and throwing errors so removed these all.